# How to use HTML Purifier with a 3rd Party Autoloader?

Tags: htmlpurifier, autoloader

I'm using this autoloader (https://gist.github.com/jwage/221634).

How do I use HTML Purifier with the above or any autoloader? I'm trying to avoid having 2 autoloaders in the same project (as HTML Purifier implements its own autoloader).

I've read HTML Purifier's documentation and can't quite figure it out.  I wonder if the standalone version of HTML Purifier is the one to use if I want to use my own autoloader.

Can anyone provide sample code for using HTML Purifier with the autoloader I am currently using, as stated on the first line above?

Answer (score 0):

I think HTML Purifier's autoloader should just work. It registers itself using the SPL mechanism and should play fine with your existing autoloader infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it a little later.